# Need help on selenium hidden elements

Tags: selenium, authentication, popup, frame

I am trying to use selenium to automatically log in the following website:
here is the link https://www.theice.com/

After I click on the log in, a log in screen comes up - I don't know what this is: frame,panel ...

I have not been successful in detecting what elements,properties this screen has through selenium. Thus I am not able to fill in the necessary info through selenium.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Cool, so what have you tried? The page seems to be pretty straightforward AJAX. Nothing fancy, no frames, no popups.

Answer (score 0):

SiKing is correct, here.  Nothing too fancy going on with the DOM.  Use your favorite DOM inspector and examine the elements and you should be able to identify the locators.

In this case, it looks like the front end devs were thorough and gave major elements 'id' tags.  Once you can establish a relationship from an element to it's id, you'll just need to code the selenium commands to interact with them.

While there are a number of good tools for this, I like to recommend FireBug and FirePath addons for Firefox.  Similarly to Chrome's inspector, hovering over a DOM element in the inspector will highlight the element itself on the page.  FirePath can assist with CSS selectors and XPath if need be.

Without knowing your method of development (code by hand or SeleniumIDE) or you chosen language, I'd simply recommend reading the Selenium docs over at http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations to get a feel for the means by which elements can be identified and subsequently used.

Incidentally, this site is an example of a good front end design (at least from a cursory glance).  Locating elements, once you're familiar with the concepts, should be relatively simple.  Play around with it, the best way to learn is by doing (that's why I haven't just given you the solution), you'll get it.

Best of luck.

(Also, I've not meant this message as 'talking down' to you.  I'm not familiar with your level of understanding here, so I'm just starting with the basics).

Edit:
It occurred to me, after writing my initial response, that you may encounter an issue with the modal being displayed.  After clicking the 'log in' link, you may want to add a wait to your test to ensure enough time for the modal to appear before interacting with it's elements.  A simple Thread.sleep() could work here, but I hate recommending that unless it's a last resort situation (we all know sleeps suck, but sometimes it just needs to be done)...  Instead, read up on the WebDriverWait class (assuming java) and the ExpectedConditions class.  You could pass a locator for the root modal element, or a child thereof into wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yourLocator")); which will wait until the condition is satisfied (or a timeout occurs) rather than the Thread.sleep() making a hard pause and possibly waiting for a needlessly long amount of time.
The point is, since the modal display isn't instantaneous, WebDriver may choke if it tries to interact with an element that hasn't yet appeared.  Using a wait will relieve this problem.